# Flink KeyBy Random Number

Tags: java, apache-flink

There is a java flink code, I want to use a random number for `keyby`,so I implemented `KeySelector`,  what is the line commented out in the following code, but there will be some issues.

1.When I set the parallelism to 1, it works will, but when  the parallelism is greater than 1, there will be an error, it occures before print "=====process".

2.When I set random numbers in the map method in advance,and keyby as a field of the MaxwellSend object,it works will no matter what the parallelism is.

`keyBy((KeySelector<MaxwellSend, Integer>) value -> new Random().nextInt(10)+1)` this dont seems to work. It seems that all the data has entered the same partition,  Why generating Random Numbers in Keyby doesn't Work ?

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.StateTable.put(StateTable.java:336)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.StateTable.put(StateTable.java:159)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapListState.add(HeapListState.java:99)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator.processElement(WindowOperator.java:394)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask$StreamTaskNetworkOutput.emitRecord(OneInputStreamTask.java:173)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskNetworkInput.processElement(StreamTaskNetworkInput.java:151)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskNetworkInput.emitNext(StreamTaskNetworkInput.java:128)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:69)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:310)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:187)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:485)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:469)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:708)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:533)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

```
    DataStreamSource<String> streamSource = env.addSource(consumer);
        SingleOutputStreamOperator<MaxwellSend> map =
                streamSource.map(data -> {
                    MaxwellSend maxwellSend = mapper.readValue(data, MaxwellSend.class);
                    maxwellSend.setRandomId(new Random().nextInt(10)+1);
                    return maxwellSend;
                });
        SingleOutputStreamOperator<DataToMySQL> process = map
            //  .keyBy((KeySelector<MaxwellSend, Integer>) value -> new Random().nextInt(10)+1)
                .keyBy(MaxwellSend::getRandomId)
                .timeWindow(Time.seconds(2))
                .process(new ProcessWindowFunction<MaxwellSend, DataToMySQL, Integer, TimeWindow>() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Integer tuple, Context context, Iterable<MaxwellSend> elements, Collector<DataToMySQL> out) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("=====process");
                    }
                });

        process.addSink(new MySQLSink());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code, and some input on your question...

1. Always include the version of Flink you are using with your question. That helps when (among other things) there's a stack trace that goes into Flink code.
2. You do NOT want to use a random value for your key, see [this
   answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62620899/231762) for more details.

3. If you use something like `keyBy((KeySelector<MaxwellSend, Integer>) value -> new Random().nextInt(10)+1)`, and your parallelism is not significantly greater than 10, you can easily get all keys assigned (via hash partitioning) to the same slot.